# Wildfly 10.1 MySQL Driver in Domain mode installation

Tags: mysql, driver, wildfly-10, wildfly-9, jconnect

It seems there is a bug of some sort regarding the installation of a the mysql jconnector driver for wildfly *domain* mode. In wildfly *standalone* all is fine. Tried it in wildfly 9 as well - same results.

Anyway, managed to get it working, after so much digging around. Hopefully it will save someone's time.

Answer (score 1):

1) Start server in domain mode

2) Download jconnector driver from: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html
*Use the development release 6.*

3) Deploy in wildfly from the web interface:
a) http://localhost:9990 -> Deployments > Content Repository > Add . After that assign and activate

4) Configuration tab -> Profiles -> Full (or other as needed) -> Datasources -> Non-XA -> Add

a) From the list select the MySQL Datasource ... then Next
b) Naming. First field something arbitrary, up to you, second field in format java:/name-up-to-you ... then Next

c) JDBC Driver setup. Using the Specify Driver tab, leave everything as it, except for the first field: "Name*:" which should be the name of the deployed driver. For me, not changing anything this was mysql-connector-java-6.0.6-bin.jar ... then Next (*some notes below)

d) Connection URL*: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my-db or whatever your db is located ... then Next and Finish

---

- The detected driver tab never showed my driver after deployment for some reason. Using standalone, with deployment it was automatically populated.

You could manually include a driver as a module by placing it in the modules/system/... directory and setting it up through the *wildfly-home*/domain/configuration/domain.xml then in the  tag find child element , then the child element , then add yours. But i couldn't make it work this way, so won't go into this.

Has anyone had such experiences?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work this way with mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar, but it works fine with mysql-connector-java-6.0.6.jar. Thanks for that hint :)